# Android: Edit Text color is not setting as black

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

In my application I have an EditText with hint , while executing I can see the hint .But while typing i can't see the text that I type.I set color parameter as  `android:textColor="#000000"` in the edit text, but could not view the text i type as black.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_searchContact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Search..."/>
    <requestFocus/>
```

Am using Theme

```
    <style name="Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Can any one please help me for the issue.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what do you mean by *good result*

Comment: can you post the image of your `EditText`?

Comment: I mean the text color is not changing to black its still in gray color

Comment: OMG !!! How is it  possible

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya   the issue see in some of phones

Comment: what is the color of text hint?

Comment: `while typing` did you using textwatcher ??

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue, the edit text hint is white on Nexus 7, but on other device, the hint is black.

```
edittext.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
```

also set it programmatically will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:textColor="@color/black">

</EditText>
```

color.xml (res/values/color.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

**Method 2:**

Try it in Activity, java code as:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

EditText et1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);        

  et1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);   


}
```

Check the link:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/627146/Android/Mobile/textColor-doesn-change-app

Comment: I already tried this, but not change. still the text color as gray

Comment: OK, check updated answer, it don't help then show the theme which you are using in app, actiivty

Comment: post  <style name="Theme.NoTitleBar"> also, and please  try my code, and check link again i posted, and also try on some other emulator, devices